# Add additional data into a multidimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, insert

The following piece of code

```
$rank = array
        (
        array($row['Name'],$passed,$target,$target2,$TotalScore)
        );
```

is temp. holding information of the total scores of a competition.

However, the complexity of my outer loop works through and totals up all the scores before it pops it into this array.

```
John West - Yes - 250 - 750 - 1000
```

Then the loop will continue this process and will then end up with a list of names and their scores - sorted of course. So basically creating a list which I can then sort and create a ranking table.

I'm not sure how the above code could be manipulated so I can insert at the next part of the array after the totalling has been done.

I remember years ago I could do something in other languages like:-
 `$rank[1][0] = Dave Burt, No, 100, 300, 400;`

Any suggestions? I got a feeling this is going to be straight forward.

Comment: `$rank[1][0] = ['Dave Burt', 'No', 100, 300, 400];` is that what you are talking about

Comment: Careful, `$rank[1][0]` will overwrite any existing data at position 0, . Better to use `$rank[1][]` to append at the end of the array.

Comment: Does the array - like I have written above have to be defined like that in order for the suggested code to work?

Comment: Additionally, I can't get that code to work. I've tested my original code with zero's and that's fine. The code suggested, makes sense, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I could simply ask - how can I make the above code that I posted, allow to add an additional line of info whenever I want?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, do in this way

You can define new_array as

```
$new_array=(" "," ",...)
```

And append it like this

```
$rank->append(new_array)
```

Comment: Thanks - never seen it done this way before but it kind of makes sense but still not working. Do I have to define the array first ($rank)?

Comment: Yes define it as  an empty array. You can't append before you define.

Comment: Why won't this work:-   `$rank = array
           (array('',0,0,0,0) );
   
   $new_array=('JULIE',1,1,1,1);
   $rank->append($new_array);